# ASIHTTPRequest in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I have been using `ASIHTTPRequest` for an application but it gives me error in `topSecretFetchFailed` method 5 out of 10 request, Not sure how to deal with it, Isn't `ASIHTTPRequest` stable enough?

```
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchFailed:)];
```

EDIT:

This is my code or method which get called in each request. MARKET_INDEXES_URL its static string which has "someurl.com";

```
- (void)requestData { 
   ASIHTTPRequest *req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:MARKET_INDEXES_URL]];
   [req setDelegate:self]; 
   [req setDidFailSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchFailed:)]; 
   [req setDidFinishSelector:@selector(topSecretFetchComplete:)]; 
   [self setRequest:req]; 
   [self.request startAsynchronous]; 
}
```

and this is the fail handler

```
- (void)topSecretFetchFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest { 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MarketIndexesError" object:nil]; 
   UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning !" message:@"Connection error, Please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
  [view show]; 
  [view release]; 
  NSLog(@"MarketIndex service Fail: %d %@", [theRequest responseStatusCode], [theRequest responseStatusMessage]); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is some reporting of the response details. Without that, you're diagnosing in the dark. Put this in your failure handler:

```
NSLog(@"Fail: %d %@", [request responseStatusCode], [request responseStatusMessage]);
```

Comment: @Dan I am receiving statuscode = 0 and statusmessage = null in my fail handler, Not sure whats happening.

Comment: Do me a favor and put these in as an "edit" on your original question, so the code is readable.

Comment: @Dan Sorry man I should have done it first time, Now its edited please take a look.

Comment: I guess ASIHTTPRequest delegate gets called when your request to url is finished or failed. Isn't it true ?

Answer (score 0):

ASIHTTPRequest is stable. You are probably getting error because either your network is down or your server is taking too long to respond.

You should try changing the ASIHTTPRequest property numberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout to something that suits you.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:....
request.numberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout=10;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, My Network is very much stable. I need to try with this property.